# List of references are not showing up with \printbibliography

Tags: latex, bibtex

I'm using overleaf. I have 2 files,main.tex and gil.bib uploaded

main.tex  :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{gil.bib}
\begin{document}
    Test test test \cite{Lee2009a}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

gil.bib :

```
@article{Lee2009a,
author = {Lee, Geun},
file = {:Users/JulianLeitner/Library/Application Support/Mendeley Desktop/Downloaded/Lee - 2009 - A Theory of Soft Power and Korea's Soft Power Strategy.pdf:pdf},
journal = {The Korean Journal of Defense Analysis},
number = {2},
pages = {205--218},
title = {{A Theory of Soft Power and Korea's Soft Power Strategy}},
volume = {21},
year = {2009}
}
```

But I get error saying I have "Empty bibliography on input line 6" and nothing works.
I'm new to Latex - hope someone can help me out.

Thanks!

Comment: The code seems to work fine. Can you share a read-only link to the overleaf project?